# Creating a dataframe in R in double loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, random-forest

I want to create a dataframe in R that would display the randomForest outputs (in-sample error and out-of-sample error) along with the number of variables and trees.

```
tmp = train[sample(nrow(train), 500),]
num_trees <- c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000)
for (n in num_trees){
  for (i in 1:8){
    forest <- randomForest(UNITS ~ FEATURE + DISPLAY + PRICE + SUB_CATEGORY + TPR_ONLY + MANUFACTURER + BASE_PRICE + STORE_NUM, data = tmp,ntree = n, mtry = i,importance = TRUE)
    predict_forest <- predict (forest, train, type = "class") #predicting insample
    print(paste0("In-sample error, node ", i,", no.trees: ", n, ": ", sqrt(mean((predict_forest - train$UNITS)^2)))) #in-sample error
    predict_forest_test<- predict(forest, test, type = "class") #predicting out-of-sample
    print(paste0("Out-of-sample error, node ", i,", no.trees: ", n, ": ", sqrt(mean((predict_forest_test - test$UNITS)^2))))#out-of-sample error
  }
}
```

So, instead of printing the results I would like to form a dataset.
1st column would be no. of trees, 2nd column would be no. of variables, 3rd and 4th columns would have the error values for all combinations of trees and variables respectively.

Cheers,
Axe

Comment: Hi weirdaxe. Can you show us what you already tried to get said data.frame? What are you struggling with?

Comment: I tried to use ''' num_trees <-c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000)
var <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
df <- data.frame(A=num_trees, b=var)
df %>%
  slice(rep(1:8, each = 10)) ''' to create a dataset in which I would then input randomForest values but really didn't manage to do a whole lot